# How to upgrade C++ version?

Tags: c++

I'm unfamiliar with C++, but something that I am trying to build requires the C++ version to be C++ 20 (it uses some features that only cpp 20 has apparently). I believe my current version is lower than that (C++ 17 or something along that line). How can I update my version of C++ to the newest version? I am on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: type c++ --version to see your current version number. 17 and 20 make no sense, I'd expect major versions like 8, 9 or 10. Now figure out what version you really need -- which features?

Comment: Check if [the particular feature is supported in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20), and if so, which version, and upgrade accordingly.

Comment: There is "highly experimental" support for the 2020 revision of the ISO C++ standard in g++-10 via the `-std=c++2a` option. You can install g++-10 on 18.04 from the toolchain-r PPA.